# {Class} is not a constructor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I am new to Typescript and I am not to get imports to work correctly. I have these two files:

**./lib/proxy/Proxy.ts**

```
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

export default class Proxy {
    private readonly target: string;

    private readonly context: string;

    private readonly options: object;

    public constructor({ context, target, ...options }: {context: string; target: string; options?: object}) {
        this.target = target;
        this.context = context;
        this.options = options;
    }

    public createDefaultProxy(): proxy.Proxy {
        return proxy({
            target: this.target,
            logLevel: process.env.NODE_ENV ? 'info' : 'debug',
            pathRewrite: {
                [`^/api/v1${this.context}`]: '/',
            },
            ...this.options,
        });
    }
}
```

**./routes/workspaceRoute.ts**

```
import Proxy from '../lib/proxy/Proxy'

class WorkspaceRoute {
    public readonly router: Router;

    public readonly context: string;

    public readonly service: string;

    public constructor(router, context, service) {
        this.router = router;
        this.context = context;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public registerProxy(proxyParams?: object) {
        console.log('11111', Proxy)
        this.router.use(
            this.context,
            new Proxy({ context: this.context, target: this.service, ...proxyParams }).createDefaultProxy(),
        );
    }
}
```

And when I try to run a dev compilation using `ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./app` I get te following error `Proxy is not a constructor`
.

It seems that the imports/exports are not working well, but as far as I understand they are ok.

For more information, here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES5",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015",                       /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                       /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
//    "strict": true,                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
     "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You have not imported `./lib/proxy/Proxy.ts` in `./routes/workspaceRoute.ts`. You must import the `Proxy` class in `WorkspaceRoute`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it to the question, I just did it.

Comment: It seems that when you run the compiler for a specific file (for example `tsc ./app.ts`) the tsconfig file is not take into account. I am executing now just `tsc` and seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you compiling only app.ts like `ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./app` ??
you should do `tsc -p <path to tsconfig.json>` it will work fine.